# Outlook Event-Driven Office Web Add-In Example for Visual Studio

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

I am looking for an Outlook Event-Driven Office Web Add-In for Visual Studio with a .sln file. Something like an add-in with an event that triggers on OnNewMessageCompose and creates a subject line or triggers on OnMessageSend and encrypts any attachments you might have. I do not need to have an associated task pane, but I would not complain if the example had one as well.

I have found multiple examples of Outlook Event-Driven Office Web Add-Ins, but I have not been able to get any of them to work in Visual Studio, which is where my limited expertise lies. What I have found are pieces of code like this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch?tabs=xmlmanifest) or complete solutions like this [one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/officedev/pnp-officeaddins/outlook-add-in-set-signature/) developed in other compilers such as Visual Studio Code, but again not incorporated into Visual Studio. I have also tried to get things to work in Visual Studio Code directly but failed miserably at this as well.

My bad for not being more expert, I know. In my defense, this is my first try at a Web Add-In and my experience is really with Visual Studio.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have gone through all of that. It is hard to switch on web development from VBA or VSTO add-ins.

In Office add-ins all event handlers don't depend on the IDE you use - VSCode or Visual Studio. The event handlers are declared in the manifest file with event handlers in the JS files. From that perspective it doesn't matter whether ASP.NET or NodeJS is used for building the solution. If you consider learning the NodeJS curve take a look at the [Build your first Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/quickstarts/outlook-quickstart?tabs=yeomangenerator) page.

Comment: Dear Eugene, Thank you for this advice.  i took a look at the web page you suggested and was able to make some progress there. Still quite a bit to do, but thank you very much for setting me on the right path. Dylan